# squid proxy ext_session_acl missing from RPM package

Tags: squid, session

After installing squid 3.1/3.2/3.3 on Fedora 18, Centos 6 or RHEL 6, the session helper file ext_session_acl is missing. Compiling from 3.3.source, it doesn't get compiled even when given argument to configure --enable-external-acl-helpers="session"  . There is something about it will be compiled IF it is possible. Has anyone manage to use this helper on Red Hat?

Thanks, John.

Soultion: The problem was caused by a check for /usr/include/db.h which was missing, therefore the compile was skipped for session. Installed libdb-devel to fix this.

ls -al /usr/include/db.h

sudo yum provides /usr/include/db.h

sudo yum install libdb-devel

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 external-acl-helpers="session"
```

I have built squid from http://repo.ngtech.co.il/rpm/centos/6/x86_64/SRPM/squid-3.3.8-1.el6.src.rpm without any problem on CentOS-6

```
# rpm -qpl /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/squid-3.3.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm | grep session
/usr/lib64/squid/ext_session_acl
/usr/share/man/man8/ext_session_acl.8.gz
```

Note: session it's just a name of the folder in squid-3.3.8/helpers/external_acl

Comment: I tried that too but still same. The problem was caused by a check for /usr/include/db.h which was missing. Installed libdb-devel to fix this.

ls -al /usr/include/db.h
sudo yum provides /usr/include/db.h
sudo yum install libdb-devel

Comment: On centos you should to install db4-devel

Comment: db4-devel is listed in the RPM spec file so will not install and will prompt you to install it. libdb-devel is not in spec file hence why I missed it. Thanks.